# Rails Tutorial ch 7.2.3 has_password? undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial, [ch 7.2.3](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#sec%3aimplementing_has_password), rspec is returns the following errors:

```
Failures:

1) User has_password? method should be true if the passwords match
 Failure/Error: @user.has_password?(@attr[:password].should be_true)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `has_password?' for nil:NilClass
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:132:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) User has_password? method should be false if the passwords don't match
 Failure/Error: @user.has_password?("invalid").should be_false
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `has_password?' for nil:NilClass
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:136:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.23931 seconds
18 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:131 # User has_password? method should be true if the  passwords match
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:135 # User has_password? method should be false if the passwords don't match
```

In the console I'm also getting an undefined local variable error on 'password confirmation'

I've thoroughly checked my code and can't find the discrepancy but I'm obviously doing it wrong.

here's my users model:

```
require 'digest'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name,  :presence   => true,
                :length     => { :maximum => 50 }   
  validates :email, :presence   => true,
                :format     => { :with => email_regex },
                :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

  # Automatically create the virtual attribute 'password_confirmation'.
  validates :password, :presence     => true,
                   :confirmation => true,
                   :length       => { :within => 6..40 }

  before_save :encrypt_password

    def has_password?(submitted_password)
      self.encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
    end

  private

    def encrypt_password
      self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
      self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
    end

    def encrypt(string)
      secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
    end

    def make_salt
      secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
    end

    def secure_hash(string)
     Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
    end

end
```

Comment: We'd need to see the spec; the issue is that what you're calling it on is nil, not that the method doesn't exist. Are you sure the appropriate test data is being loaded and retrieved?

Comment: How are you setting @user in your spec?  Sounds like you haven't initialised it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure this bit is in your spec, sounds like it's missing

```
before(:each) do
  @user = User.create!(@attr)
end
```

Comment: Yes, this was missing from the has_password? method. Thanks!